# discord.js bot not responding to slash commands but the commands are registered

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I started programming a discord bot with nodejs on replete and I use code similar to the example in the official site of discord.js. Bot registered the command and it appears in discord but when I run it doesn't work.

```
The application did not respond
```

This is the code I use to make the command:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('hi')
        .setDescription('say hi'),
    async execute(interaction) {
    await interaction.reply('hi');
    },
};
```

The index code:

```js
const { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const token = process.env['TOKEN']
const clientId = process.env['APID']
const guildId = process.env['SID']
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

//
const { REST, Routes } = require('discord.js');
/*const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');*/
const fs = require('node:fs');

const commands = [];
// Grab all the command files from the commands directory you created earlier
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

// Grab the SlashCommandBuilder#toJSON() output of each command's data for deployment
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

// Construct and prepare an instance of the REST module
const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(token);

// and deploy your commands!
(async () => {
    try {
        console.log(`Started refreshing ${commands.length} application (/) commands.`);

        // The put method is used to fully refresh all commands in the guild with the current set
        const data = await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId),
            { body: commands },
        );

        console.log(`Successfully reloaded ${data.length} application (/) commands.`);
    } catch (error) {
        // And of course, make sure you catch and log any errors!
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
//
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Bot is online!");
})

client.login(process.env['TOKEN']);
```

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhzmQ.png)

[Command Registered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c78aE.png)

[Bot Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5k44.png)

[Bot Scopes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYOzk.png)

[Bot Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCp8A.png)

Comment: Please help me this is the last chance to solve my problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I can't see any event listener here (apart from the `ready` event). Where do you call the `execute` method?

Comment: Tanks so much I forget to put the event listener tanks so much.